# Probability random n-bit integer has an m-bit factor

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Define an $n$ bit integer to be an integer in the range $[2^{n-1},2^n]$.

Let $n\gg m$. What is the asymptotic probability that a random $n$-bit integer $N$ has an $m$-bit factor x? $N$ may also have multiple $m$-bit factors.

Note that $x$ does not need to be prime. So if, say, $N$ had two prime factors $p_1,p_2$ such that $x=p_1p_2$ was $m$ bits, this would count as $N$ having an $m$-bit factor.

A very rough heuristic calculation would suggest that the probability is constant, independent of $n,m$. In particular, for each $m$-bit integer $x$, the probability $x$ divides $N$ is approximately $1/x$. Assuming divisibility are independent events for all $m$-bit integers would then give the probability of having an $m$-bit factor as:

$$1-\prod_{x=2^{m-1}}^{2^m-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{2^{m-1}}{2^{m}-1}\approx \frac{1}{2}$$

I'm somewhat skeptical of this estimate, however, as the divisibility events definitely are not independent, since various different $x$ will share common factors. I'm therefore looking for a more refined estimate.

Answer (score 1):

No big deal but $2^n$ is NOT an $n$ bit number, it's the smallest $n+1$ bit number.

I am not an expert but, if
the smallest prime divisor of $N$ is denoted by $P^{-1}(N),$ then
$$
\Phi(x,y)=\#\{n\leq x: P^{-}(N)>y\},
$$
is the counting function of $y-$rough numbers. Note that if the smallest prime dividing $N$ is $\geq 2^m$ then $N$ does not have an $m-$bit divisor.
Now,
$$
\Phi(x,y) \sim \omega(u) \frac{x}{\log y}
$$
where $\omega(u)$ is the [Buchstab function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchstab_function) and $u=\log x/\log y$.

Using the above estimate the probability you want averaged over $x\in [2^{n-1},2^n-1]$ can be written as
$$
\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \sum_{x=2^{n-1}}^{2^n-1} \Phi(x,2^m).
$$

The paper [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/INTEGERS-WITH-A-LARGE-SMOOTH-DIVISOR-Banks-Shparlinski/ebb982e2c118508f2cb8d6ec3eea04df35ef9925?p2df) has further estimates which may or may not help evaluate this quantity. I would be interested in finding out if there is a simpler answer.